# C - Dynamically sized array of struct pointers without using realloc?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

I need help with a school assignment, specifically with resizing the amount of memory allocated for a pointer WITHOUT realloc.

I have the following declarations in my program.

```
struct GraphicElement
{
    enum{ SIZE = 256 };
    unsigned int numLines;
    Line* pLines;
    char name[SIZE];
};

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned int numGraphicElements;
    GraphicElement* pElements;
}VectorGraphic;

VectorGraphic Image;
```

As the program runs I'll be adding more GraphicElements to pElements.

For example, after 5 iterations the memory for pElements should be something like this:

[GraphicElement 0][GraphicElement 1] ... [GraphicElement 4]

---

For the function AddGraphicElement(VectorGraphic* vg) I have this code (with some lines removed for easier reading):

```
vg->pElements = (GraphicElement*)realloc(vg->pElements, sizeof(GraphicElement)*(vg->numGraphicElements+1));

//Then I assign inputs from user into the members of the struct at vg->pElements[vg->numGraphicElements]

vg->numGraphicElements++;
```

---

This works, BUT according to the instructions given by my professor, I'm only allowed to use malloc and free- no realloc. Sadly the only way I've made this work is with realloc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to implement this using only malloc?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`/`realloc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use `realloc`, but `malloc` and `free` are allowed, you can replace the call with the following, less efficient, sequence:

```
void *newData = malloc(newSize);
memcpy(newData, oldData, oldSize);
free(oldData);
```

Internally, `realloc` does the same thing, but it does so more efficiently. Unlike user program, `realloc` knows the actual size of the dynamic memory chunk, so it checks if `newSize <= actualSize` to avoid reallocation. When `actualSize` is insufficient, `realloc` does the same thing as above. `realloc` has additional logic to deal with situations when the size need to shrink, but in your situation this does not apply.

Comment: Technically `realloc` does `memcpy(newData, oldData, min(oldSize, newSize))` but that makes no difference in this case because the size just keeps growing.

Comment: @melpomene Right, `realloc` needs to be smarter than that. This should be sufficient for OP, though, because for his program memory allocation is a one-way street.

Comment: @melpomene If you want to be technical, then a true `realloc` implementation also would need to return the original pointer on allocation failure and avoid the `memcpy` step if the original pointer is the null pointer.

Comment: @jamesdlin Absolutely. However, since OP is not looking to implement `realloc`, I gave him only the details that he needs to complete his assignment.